# Do something on onkeypress and onpaste event

Tags: javascript

I'm trying this

```
textarea.onkeypress = function() {
    isModified = true;
};
textarea.onpaste = function() {
    isModified = true;
};
```

my question is that can I combine these into a single condition?
how can I use OR operator here. so that isModified returns true on onkeypress or onpaste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just write the function and pass it in to both calls:

```
var callback = function() {
    isModified = true;
};

textarea.onpaste = textarea.onkeypress = callback;
```

Comment: should I do this? or below one would be ok?
`textarea.onkeypress = function() {
    isModified = true;
};
textarea.onpaste = function() {
    isModified = true;
};`

Comment: @Juhana no difference. I mean are there any benefits of using Mash's method or it would be ok to use my method?

Comment: Benefits are that you can later update the method only in once place instead of two or more places.

Comment: how about this:
`textarea.onpaste = textarea.onkeypress = function() {
    isModified = true;
};`

Answer (score 0):

You should handle the `input` event, which is raised on keystrokes, paste, cut, drag&drop, and all other forms of input.